# How to convert this line of code from C# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am converting a codeblock from C# to VB.NET using the http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

All is going well except for one line which I cannot figure how to convert:

**C# source**

```
result.DrawPolyline(Array.ConvertAll<PointF, Point>(pts, Point.Round), true, new Bgr(Color.Red), 5);
```

**Using the converter gives this**

```
result.DrawPolyline(Array.ConvertAll(Of PointF, Point)(pts, Point.Round), True, New Bgr(Color.Red), 5)
```

The error in the above line is:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'value' of 'Public Shared
>   Function Round(value As System.Drawing.PointF) As
>   System.Drawing.Point'.

Comment: Maybe VB.Net thinks Point.Round is a function and not the value of an enum, and thus asks you a parameter.
What happens in your intellisense (or same) when you type `Point.` after `(pts, ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should convert an Array of PointF to Point:

```
result.DrawPolyline(Array.ConvertAll(Of PointF, Point)(pts, Function(p) Point.Round(p)), True, New Bgr(Color.Red), 5)
```

You need to pass the `PointF` to  [Point.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.round.aspx).

Tested with:

```
Dim pts As PointF() = {New PointF(123.23, 12345.23)}
Dim r = Array.ConvertAll(Of PointF, Point)(
            pts,
            Function(p) Point.Round(p))
```

It would also work if you would pass the delegate to `Point.Round` as @Jon has mentioned:

```
Dim pts As PointF() = {New PointF(123.23, 12345.23)}
Dim r = Array.ConvertAll(Of PointF, Point)(
            pts,
            AddressOf Point.Round)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `Array.ConvertAll` should be the a the method used for the conversion (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx))

Its possible that the line is missing the `AddressOf` before the `Point.Round` call, so that the method is passed as the delegate, rather than being executed, as follows:

```
result.DrawPolyline(Array.ConvertAll(Of PointF, Point)(pts, AddressOf Point.Round), True, New Bgr(Color.Red), 5)
```